# Нужна ли запятая? «Если у вас уже куплена камера, и вы что-то ей снимали...»

Tags: пунктуация

В книге Е. Сапожинского «Серебряный мир» есть предложение:

> Если у Вас уже куплена камера, и Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите
> научиться снимать по-настоящему, то отложите ее, пусть полежит хотя бы
> несколько дней.

Нужна ли запятая после слова «камера»?

Возможно, предложение должно выглядеть так?

**Если у вас уже куплена камера и вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему, то отложите ее, пусть полежит хотя бы несколько дней.**

Заранее благодарен всем ответившим.

Comment: Тут не до запятой (она лишняя): если камера у вас уже куплена, то вам её не отложить!

Comment: @shampar Вы изменили прописные буквы на строчные, однако у автора буквы прописные. Он везде так пишет в своей книге: «Вы», «Вас» и т. д. Видимо, этим подчёркивается, что обращение идёт к одному человеку, конкретному читателю, которой читает сейчас, а не к читателям в целом. Автор как бы создаёт непосредственный уважительный диалог с тем, кто читает в данный момент. Ошибкой большая бука является при обращении к нескольким людям. После вашего исправления авторских больших букв, теперь в моём ответе они выглядят как моя ошибка.

Comment: @shampar Тут не стоит вопрос о правильности прописных букв автора, а вопрос касается запятой. Поэтому я считаю, что текст должен быть сохранён, как у автора.

Comment: Хорошо. Я нашёл книжку. Да, Вы правы.

Comment: @shampar Спасибо, что исправили и внимательно отнеслись.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы предложили **единственно корректную** грамматику:

*(1) **Если** у вас уже куплена камера и (2) вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему, (3) **то** отложите ее,  (4) пусть полежит хотя бы несколько дней.*

Пояснение

В основе сложной конструкции лежат отношения **условия** между предложениями (1) и (2) и предложениями(3) и (4)  Их лучше связать **двойным союзом** ЕСЛИ…ТО.

Однородные придаточные (1) и (2) связаны **одиночным союзом И**, поэтому запятая не ставится.

В предложении (2) **союз НО** связывает однородные сказуемые.

Comment: *«В предложении (2) союз НО связывает однородные сказуемые»*. Как это они однородные, если у них разное время и разные вопросы? «Снимали» и «хотите» не являются однородными сказуемыми к подлежащему «Вы».
«Вы» *что делали?* «снимали», «Вы» *что делаете?* «хотите» — разные вопросы, разное время. В чём же их однородность?

Comment: «Вы предложили **единственно корректную** грамматику». Кто предложил?

Comment: *"Их лучше связать двойным союзом ЕСЛИ…ТО".* Лучше, чем что? В предложении автора они так и связаны. Кто-то спрашивал что-то насчёт союза? Вопрос был про запятую.

Comment: @Eagle На запятую (которая здесь не нужна), наличие "то" не влияет, хотя и проясняет схему с общим членом "если": если А и В, то С.

Comment: @Alex_ander Я в своих комментариях к этому ответу ничего не говорил, про «то». О чём вы сейчас говорите?

Comment: "Их лучше связать двойным союзом ЕСЛИ…ТО". Лучше, чем что? (Eagle 6 часов назад) ////   Я в своих комментариях к этому ответу ничего не говорил, про «то».  (Eagle 4 часа назад)

Comment: @shampar  Вы собираете мои цитаты? Что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: @Sharon, сколько же дилетантства на этом форуме,уж и не знаю, плакать ли или смеяться... Да хорошо бы было, если б на нем все кончалось, но на вас, как обычно, обрушились с непробудным и непрошибаемым до тошноты хамством и наглостью.  Ваш ответ, как всегда, точен и доступен. Спасибо, что так трепетны к нашему родному языку и просвещаете других, хоть некоторым, как видно, это вовсе и не нужно. Я вам буду всегда благодарен за то, что открыли мне удивительной красоты мир русского языка, и ваш вклад в мое будущее нельзя переоценить.

Comment: Игорь,  я тоже вам благодарна, у меня все надежды на БУДУЩЕЕ ПОКОЛЕНИЕ.   В нашем народе, в нашем языке неистощимый запас  духовной силы, хочется в это верить.  Всё изменится, придут лучшие времена. Хотя я не планирую активно работать на форуме, но на ваши вопросы и  другие интересные темы по грамматике и пунктуации постараюсь отвечать. Для вас, для тех, кто по-настоящему любит язык. Еще раз спасибо вам.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая скорее нужна, чем не нужна.

---

**Сначала почему запятая может быть не нужна** в *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера, и Вы что-то ей снимали…»* перед «и»:

> ...если предложения однородны и соединены союзом И, запятая между ними не ставится. [[mogu-pisat.ru](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.B5.20.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5.20.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B51.1.1)]

*«...у Вас уже куплена камера…»* и *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»* — это однородные предложения, соединённые союзом «И».

> Однородными называются предложения, которые имеют некую общую
> структуру: **общее главное предложение**, общее придаточное предложение,
> общее вводное слово или общий второстепенный член. Эти предложения
> **соединены** или могут быть соединены **сочинительными союзами**,
> **произносятся с интонацией перечисления**. [[mogu-pisat.ru](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)]

- *«…то отложите ее…»* — общее главное предложение.
- *«и»* — сочинительный союз в *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера и Вы что-то ей снимали…»*.
- Имеет место перечисление: *«Если (1 — у Вас уже куплена камера) и (2 — Вы что-то ей снимали)…»*.

> Придаточные [предложения]... **относятся к одному и тому же слову главной части** или
> ко всей главной части в целом, к ним **задаются одинаковые вопросы** и,
> как правило,  они **вводятся одинаковыми союзами** или союзными словами. [[mogu-pisat.ru](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)]

- *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера…»* и *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»* относятся к одному и тому же слову (сказуемому) **«отложите»** главной части ***«...то отложите ее...»***.
- К ним задаётся одинаковый вопрос от сказуемого **«отложите»** главной части: **в каком случае?** *«…у Вас уже куплена камера…»*; **в каком случае?** *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»*.
- Они вводятся одним и тем же союзом «если»: «**Если** у Вас уже куплена камера…», «**Если**… Вы что-то ей снимали…».

Таким образом, предложения *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера…»* и *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»* являются однородными, и их соединяет сочинительный союз «и» — следовательно, складывается впечатление, что **запятая не нужна**.

Для сравнения пример с сайта [mogu-pisat.ru](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> *Когда подтает и снег станет липким, мы пойдём делать снеговика.*
>
> *Мы пойдём делать снеговика (когда?) когда подтает.*
>
> *Мы пойдём делать снеговика (когда?) когда снег станет липким.*
>
> В примере от сказуемого главного предложения задаётся один вопрос.
> Предложения однородны. Их соединяет союз **И**. Предложения не разделяются
> запятой.

---

**Теперь почему запятая может быть нужна:**

В аргументации выше упущен важный момент, а именно наличие предложения *«…но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»*.

На самом деле условия следующие:

- «**Если** у Вас уже куплена камера…»;
- «**Если**… Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…».

Эти два условия соединяются союзом «и».

Соединяются не два простых предложения, а **простое** *«…у Вас уже куплена камера…»* и **сложное** *«…Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»*.

Кто-то может возразить, и сказать, что *«…Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»* простое предложение.

Однако «снимали» и «хотите» не являются однородными сказуемыми к подлежащему «Вы».
«Вы» *что делали?* «снимали», «Вы» *что делаете?* «хотите» — разные вопросы, разное время.

Условная часть к главному предложению ***«...то отложите ее...»*** состоит из простого и сложного предложения, соединённых союзом *«и»*.

Вот эта условная часть:
*«Если у Вас уже куплена камера, и Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»*.

Если посмотреть на неё внимательно, то видно, что предложение *«…но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»* не относится к *«…у Вас уже куплена камера…»*, а относится только к *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»*.

Есть связь:
*«Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему»*,
но нет связи:
*«Если у Вас уже куплена камера…, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему»*.

Предложения *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера…»* и *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»* не являются однородными по отношению к *«…но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»*. *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера…»* вообще к нему не относится.
*«…но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…»* не является общей частью к *«Если у Вас уже куплена камера…»* и *«…Вы что-то ей снимали…»*. Поэтому складывается впечатление, что **запятая нужна**.

---

Я считаю, что запятая нужна.

Comment: _«…но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…» не является общей частью к «Если у Вас уже куплена камера…» и «…Вы что-то ей снимали…». Поэтому складывается впечатление, что запятая нужна._ Но разве общей частью не является предложение «...то отложите ее...»? Если его считать общей частью, то получается, что предложения «Если у Вас уже куплена камера…» и «…Вы что-то ей снимали…» являются однородными по отношению к «...то отложите ее...». При этом «…но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…» относится только к «…Вы что-то ей снимали…».

Comment: Если отметить части предложения скобками, получится так: [Если у Вас уже куплена камера] и [Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему], [то отложите ее, пусть полежит хотя бы несколько дней].

Comment: К вопросу об однородных членах разного времени и вида. "Я говорил, говорю, и буду говорить" // однородные сказуемые разного времени". "2 Новости: Петя едет туда и Вася уехал оттуда" // однородные фразы

Comment: @user190920 [skysmart.ru](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/odnorodnye-chleny-predlozheniya): *«Правило звучит так. Если два или более члена предложения относятся к одному и тому же слову, **отвечают на один и тот же вопрос**, являются одним и тем же членом предложения, то они являются однородными членами предложения».* «Вы» *что делали?* «снимали», «Вы» *что делаете?* «хотите» — разные вопросы. В чём же их однородность?

Comment: @user190920 «„Я говорил, говорю, и буду говорить“ // однородные сказуемые разного времени» — если они однородные, почему запятая перед «и»?

Comment: @user190920 «Новости: Петя едет туда и Вася уехал оттуда» — тут другое правило. [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133): *Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая **не ставится**, если части сложносочиненного предложения **объединены каким-либо общим элементом**. Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.)*

Comment: Вопрос в первую очередь касается запятой перед "и". В первой половине ответа вы говорите, что «...то отложите ее...» является общей частью, во второй половине вы это предложение не учитываете, хотя оно остается общей частью, даже если второе придаточное считать сложным. Вот предложение из справочника Лопатина, третье придаточное сложное: _Очень раздумывать, однако, о том, что двоилось у меня в глазах или на самом деле след был двойной и как могло быть, что от одной птицы шел двойной след, — времени у меня не было_ http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg119.php

Comment: @athlonusm По вашей ссылке речь идёт о другом правиле: «Если однородные придаточные части соединены разными одиночными сочинительными союзами, запятые между ними не ставятся». Ведь у нас тут не разные союзы, а один.

Comment: @athlonusm Я не учитываю его, а считаю, что наверху по иерархии идёт условное приложение: "Если ..., то", в условие которого вложено сложно предложение «Если у Вас уже куплена камера, и Вы что-то ей снимали, но хотите научиться снимать по-настоящему…», и если мы рассмотрим это предложение как целую единицу, то в нём нужна запятая.